# <input> doesn't behave when I minimize the webpage

Tags: html, css

I have three `<input type="text">` in my div. When i drag the window and make the website smaller, `<input>` doesn't stay in the div because it's not getting smaller as the div does. I want my form to look nice when it's small, **without a scrollbar** (because I tried that and it still looked bad inside the "scrollwindow")

*I recorded the problem in a Gyazo Gif:*
https://gyazo.com/7373020de6605d2d0884a60fee129446

If there's no solution, i'd love to understand why it behaves that way. Thanks!

```css
#one {
  width: 45vw;
  height: 65vw;
  background-color: gray;
  margin: auto;
}
.text {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5vw;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}
input {
  border:none;
  outline: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float:left;
}
#big {
  margin-top: 1%;
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: 15%;
}
#left {
  width: 34.5%;
  margin-left: 15%;
  margin-right: 1%;
  margin-top: 1%;
}
#right{
  width: 34.5%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  margin-right: 15%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="one">
        <div class="text">
            <input type="text" id="big">
            <input type="text" id="left">
            <input type="text" id="right">
       </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have set a fixed height to the div with red background. Any reason not to let it grow with its content? If you put up a working snippet ie including the basic html it will be easier to show a solution,

Comment: Snippet is added now

Comment: As said by @AHaworth, remove fixed height in `#one`

Comment: @AHaworth , should I replace "height: 5vw;" in the red div to another height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the red div has been set to a fixed height.

This snippet makes minimal change to your code by setting min height to 5vw so the red never goes below that but the actual height to auto. It takes the float lefts away (a floated item does not have height in the way needed here) but floats the last input right.

```css
#one {
  width: 45vw;
  height: 65vw;
  background-color: gray;
  margin: auto;
}
.text {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 5vw;
  height: auto;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}
input {
  border:none;
  outline: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#big {
  margin-top: 1%;
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: 15%;
}
#left {
  width: 34.5%;
  margin-left: 15%;
  margin-right: 1%;
  margin-top: 1%;
}
#right{
  width: 34.5%;
  margin-top: 1%;
  margin-right: 15%;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="one">
        <div class="text">
            <input type="text" id="big">
            <input type="text" id="left">
            <input type="text" id="right">
       </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

However, you may like to look at say grid as a way of laying out the areas in which you want the inputs to be as float is really designed for a different purpose, allowing content to float around a floated image.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I saw that you added "height:auto", though i can't see why its necessary, but i'd love to know why!

Comment: Hi, yes only to make it clear what is happening, it’s not essential as it’s the default.